# Why do I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Running a node server and I am getting the following error.

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

```
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
    return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
  };
}

function log_me(msg){
  var ts = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3600000*4));
  var tss = ts.toString();
  tss = tss.substring(0, tss.indexOf(' GMT'));
  console.log(tss + ": " + msg);
}

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var postData = "";
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      postData += chunk; //Get the POST data
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      if (typeof(postData) !== "undefined") {
        var message = JSON.parse(postData);  <-- Here is the issue line 25

        //Do something here
        //Todo...
      }
    });
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);  //Use a non-standard port so it doesn't override your Apache

var io = socketio.listen(app);
//var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080,'0.0.0.0');
io.set('log level', 2);
// io.set('transports', ['flashsocket', 'polling', 'websocket']);
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Comment: Maybe `postData` isn't valid JSON??

Comment: `log_me(postData);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
JSON.safeParse = function(data) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Change your `JSON.parse` call to `JSON.safeParse`, and then check if the result is valid:

```
var message = JSON.safeParse(postData);
if (message) {
    // valid!
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Comment: This really just keeps the status quo: OP already did not know what was going on prior to asking the question, and the same will apply after using this idea...